¿Como cambiar entre versiones de JDK en Linux Debian?
Instale en mi Linux Debian 11 de 64 Bits JDK de Oracle version 17 y 21 así como el OpenJDK versión 17 y 21.
Cuando ejecuto en el terminal el comando
sudo update-alternatives --config javac

Me aparece las 4 versiones de JDK instalas y que elija cual deseo utilizar para trabajar. Mi problema es que si escojo Oracle JDK 21 al ejecutar el comando
 java --version 

Me sale que la version que me esta corriendo en el computador es OpenJDK 17 que fue la primera version que instale y no la 21 de Oracle
openjdk 17.0.11 2024-04-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.11+9-Debian-1deb11u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.11+9-Debian-1deb11u1, mixed mode, sharing)

¿El comando sudo update-alternatives --config javaccambia el compilador pero no cambia la versión que esta corriendo?¿Como se cambia esta? Gracias y disculpen la molestia.

No sé bien si existe alguna forma fácil de elegir la versión que estás usando pero sí que puedes actualizar las variables de entorno JAVA_HOME y PATH para que apunten a determinada versión.

Cambiando las variables de entorno de Linux Debian. Ok voy a averiguar como se hace en Youtube ya que nunca lo he echo.. Gracias

Averigua la diferencia entre JDK y JRE; prueba con --config java.

Mi consejo es usar SDKMAN: Es una herramienta muy cómoda que permite instalar distintas JDK y elegir en cada momento cuál está activa. Incluso se puede automatizar para que al entrar en un directorio se cambie la versión (https://sdkman.io/install)

Puedes probar los siguientes comandos:
  // modificar, tienes que cambiar lo que está después del **=**, por la ruta donde está 
  // descomprimida tu **JVM**  
$ export JAVA_HOME=/home/javauser/jdk/jdk-22

  // comprobar  
$ echo $JAVA_HOME

  // actualizar path  
$ export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

  // otra comprobación  
$ which java

Gracias a @Mateo por el comentario.
Esto establece la variable "path", pero de forma efímera, cuando cierras la consola, vuelve al valor original.
Para hacerlo permanente, debes edotar el archivo /etc/environment, que debe quedar parecido a:
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-12.0.1/bin"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-12.0.1/bin/java"

Por supuesto que loque viene después de usr/local/games: y después de JAVA-HOME= lo debes cambiar por las rutas que apuntan a los respectivos ejecutables (bin y java).
Luego debes actualizar la información desde la consola con:
source "/etc/environment"
echo -e ’export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-12.0.1"\nextport PATH="$PATH:${JAVA_HOME}/bin"’ | sudo tee /etc/profile.d/jdk12.sh

Acá, la primer ruta, apunta al directorio de tu Jvm, y la segunda al archivo */etc/profile.d y jdk12.sh ese el nombre de tu JVM, al que solo debes nodificarle el número (ejem: jdk17.sh).
Volvemos a verificar:
sudo update-alternatives --display java
echo $JAVA_HOME
java -version
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
echo $RUTA

Y finalizamos con:
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-12.0.1/bin/java" 0
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-12.0.1/bin/javac" 0
sudo update-alternatives --set java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-12.0.1/bin/java
sudo update-alternatives --set javac /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-12.0.1/bin/javac

Ahora si, la casa está en orden.

¿Esos comands que me acabas de escribir son para cambiar las variables de entorno en Linux en la terminal?
export JAVA_HOME=/home/javauser/jdk/jdk-22
echo $JAVA_HOME
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
which java
Ok voy a leer mas de eso y buscar la ruta en mi computadora.

Hola Marcos, si, se hace desde la terminal.

@Marco creo que el cambio es temporal y solo dura para los procesos que abras con la misma terminal. Si quisieras hacerlos permanentes probablemente tendrías que modificar algún archivo del sistema. Algo así https://stackoverflow.com/a/14638025/13419694

@Mateo, gracias por la corrección, ya acomodé la respuesta.

Pude hacer los cambios de forma temporal para ejecutar el JVM que yo desee pero   hacer los cambios de manera permanente veo que debo dar varios pasos que me medio confunden. Voy a instalar una maquina virtual con mi misma version de Debian y hacer los cambios alli. Si todo me sale bien lo hago en mi computadora. Si rompo algo no correre el peligro de dañar mi sistema operativo. Muchas gracias otra vez

Hola de nuevo, me parece muy bien el que tomes todos los recaudos, presta especial atención a cambiar las rutas que puse por las rutas de tu JVM.
